# How can i pass HTTPS to another server

Tags: nginx, https

What im trying to do is have Nginx sit in the middle on a dedicated server and then when it sees a connection on

```
anything.(localport).vm.example.net
```

it passes the connection to 127.0.0.1:localport (http)
and to 127.0.0.1:localport2 (https, the 2 is the diffrence)

I have it working for http. but for https i need to be able to let the server its passing the connection to set up the SSL.

here is my current nginx config

```
server {
    listen 195.154.156.215:80;
    server_name ~^(.[^\.]+)(\.)(\d+)\.vm\.example\.net$;

    location / {
      access_log off;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$3;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    error_page 501 502 503 /VM-Offline.html;
    location = /VM-Offline.html {
      root   /var/www/html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work because nginx needs to read the `Host` header to route the requests. If you want to use TLS, nginx needs to be the endpoint, or it won't be able to read the header. As far as I know nginx can't read the SNI to route the requests.

That means you have to terminate the requests in the nginx proxy or it won't work.

## EDIT

I was wrong. The nginx stream module does support reading the SNI and extracting the hostname with the [ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html). This extracts the hostname from the SNI and makes it accessible vie the `$ssl_preread_server_name` variable. The module is not built by default though.

Comment: If Nginx doesn't understand SNI, then perhaps Nginx could be replaced with something which does understand SNI.

Comment: @kasperd I am not aware of any server that can intercept the ClientHello for the SNI message. Terminating SSL in Nginx is the better solution, especially now that LetsEncrypt allows Wildcards.

Comment: Extracting the hostname from the SNI field in the ClientHello message and using that to choose a backend is really easy. I find it hard to believe that I would be the only one who has done it. When I implemented http://v4-frontend.netiter.com/ I needed just 42 lines of code to support SNI.

Comment: You are right. I dug a bit deeper and the Stream module can extract the SNI: http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html

Comment: HAProxy does it too. It's not all that difficult.

Comment: Is till don't think it is a good idea with things like encrypted SNI coming to browsers now.

Answer (score 0):

Christopher Perrin is right that Nginx will need to terminate the SSL, but after it does you should be able to proxy pass to https again to the local daemon. [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/583374/configure-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-with-upstream-ssl#583397) addresses a similar issue.

I'm a little confused about the flow of the routing though, you say the request comes in over the public port, and gets routed to two local ports?